# Why can I use .Select on an observable that is not a list?

Tags: .net, reactiveui

The `Select` extension from `System.Reactive.Linq` is [documented as :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh244306(v=vs.103))

> Projects each element of an observable sequence into a new form with the specified source and selector.

This behavior sounds only applicable to Lists or IEnumerable-like objects. However I can do this with no issue :

```
IObservable<int> observable = Observable.Return(42);
observable.Select(e => "");
```

Why does this code compiles and executes successfully ? Why is it allowed ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed? You create an `IObservable<string>` using an extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are used to the `Select` method that is defined as an extension method defined on `IEnumerable<T>`. That method runs a method for each item in the sequence to transform the input `IEnumerable<T>` into an output `IEnumerable<U>` which can be of different type.

The `Select` method defined on `IObservable<T>` is the reactive counterpart of that method and transforms each value emitted by an `Observable<T>` and hence creates an `Observable<U>`.

In general, there is kind of a symmetry between the Linq extension methods defined on `IEnumerable<T>` and the reactive extension methods defined on `IObservable<T>`. You can think of an `IObservable<T>` as a sequence of items that come in one by one over time.

In your example, you define an observable emitting only one value `42` analog to an `IEnumerable<int>` that contains only one value. The `Select` statement transforms this observable into an `IObservable<string>` which emits one empty string.

The question is now when this value will be emitted: Reactive extensions has a deferred execution logic which is also similar to the deferred execution known from common Linq. This means that the value of the observable will be emitted the moment you subscribe to that observable.

Answer (score 0):

From your link to doc about method:
`Observable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IObservable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)`

`Observable.Select` is an extension method for `IObservable<TSource>`.

Comment: I'm unsure why this answer my question, could you elaborate ?

Comment: You are asking about `Observable.Select` that is an extension method to `IObservable<TSource>`. It works with observables, it is not connected with list or enumerable. Has same name, but different definition.